An example of iTalki's AI lesson summary?
Reddit's r/iTalki has quite a few posts about iTalki's upcoming iTalki Pro.  Piecing together various posts:

the teacher and student can allow iTalki to record the class, and the AI generates a report (it's also used to train their AI, or maybe even to sell to third parties);
teachers who "opt in" get preferential search ranking and the label "Pro Teacher" (source);
it's currently free but iTalki has mentioned charging students $19.99 per month (source), and none of this will go to their teachers.

(Apparently there were help pages here and here, but those links don't seem to work anymore, and I didn't find them on archive.org.)


Image source: Dear italki tutors, did you try AI lesson summary ?? what is it??, Reddit.

This is clearly a very unpopular feature on Reddit, although one student mentioned they "kinda liked the lesson summaries" (source) and one teacher wrote "my students love being able to get the AI-generated lesson summaries" (source).  This comment suggests that teachers can edit the AI lesson summaries.
I'm just wondering if I can see an example of an iTalki AI lesson summary.
